# To move cursor of textfield from active one to newly appended textfield on enter key pressed from keyboard only if active textfield is filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### html

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>item</th>
<th>Cost</th>
</thead>
 <tbody id="tbody">
<tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="elm" />
    </td>
</tr>


</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>
        <label id="total">0</label>
    </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

### jquery

```
$('body').on('keyup','.elm',function(e){
//Check Key Press is Enter
if (e.keyCode != 13) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.elm').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '' && !isNaN($(this).val())){
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $('#total').text(sum);
}
else{
var $itemNum = $('#tbody tr');
if($itemNum.find('input').val().length > 0) 
{
    var itemNum = $('#tbody tr').length + 1;
    var newRow = '<tr>'+
        '<td>Item'+itemNum+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<input type="text" class="elm">'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>';
    $('#tbody').append(newRow);
}
}
});
```

i am using above code to add number values as user enters dynamically ,by appending new textfield by pressing enter key in keyboard irrespective of number of inputs user enters and calculate its output automatically. By pressing EnterKey ,i should append new textfield only after user has entered value in previous textfield and cursor should move to new textfield automatically.
but in my code its happening only for first textfield and not same for other,please help me in coding i am new to javascript.

Comment: just add last() to the $item num row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/72ene5ob/

Hey, it looks like you want to check the lenght of the last input field only. so just add `.last()` to your selector: var $itemNum = $('#tbody tr').last();

```
$('body').on('keyup','.elm',function(e){
//Check Key Press is Enter
    console.log(e.keyCode);
if (e.keyCode != 13) {
    console.log('Enter detected');
    var sum = 0;
    $('.elm').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '' && !isNaN($(this).val())){
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $('#total').text(sum);
}
else{
var $itemNum = $('#tbody tr').last();

if($itemNum.find('input').val().length > 0) 
{
    console.log('should add new input');
    var itemNum = $('#tbody tr').length + 1;
    var newRow = '<tr>'+
        '<td>Item'+itemNum+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<input type="text" class="elm">'+
        '</td>'+
    '</tr>';
    $('#tbody').append(newRow);
}
}
});
```

Comment: This is not correct just i run this jsfiddle with out .last(); It is working fine for me. I hope he need to include the jquery script file on the page.

Comment: Thankyou sir this is what i was tring to do from two days finally you helped me to do this.

Comment: please explain me what is the need of setTimeout(function(){ $('.elm').last().focus();}, 0);

Comment: @David Karlsson, if i want to reset to initial  that is removing all appended textfields with having only initial textfield unfilled by pressing delete key in keyboard ,what should i add

Answer (score 0):

I extended David Karlsson's answer by adding the following line of code as the last line in the else block:

```
     $('#tbody tr:last-child td:last-child input').focus();
```

Following that, the newly added line's input gets the focus.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/72ene5ob/1/)

Comment: if i want to reset to initial position that is removing all appended textfields with having only initial textfield unfilled by pressing delete key in keyboard ,what should i add

Comment: I guess you need to check for keyup event for key 46 (delete), and then use the following selector to remove all but first row: $('#tbody tr:not(:first)').remove();   after that  $('#tbody tr:first-child td:last-child input').val("");